# Unable to get Entire string in SerialMonitor and server stops on error

Tags: node.js, socket.io, arduino

In my work, i am trying to pass the data into node Server through arduino serial, and then connect slaves to server through socketIO..but the problem is i am unable to get the entire string from arduino into server...(i get disorted data)..how can i fix this...please help!

the string in  should be like this **(JSON) :  {"key":"value","key":"value"}** 
 error is as follows:

```
Server running on http://192.168.2.7:8000
Connected: 1 sockets connected
undefined:1
{"00","Humidity":"59.00"}
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
at Object.parse (native)
at SerialPort.<anonymous>     (/home/manoj/Documents/ESHATS/server.js:51:40)
at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at SerialPort.emit (events.js:182:7)
at /home/manoj/Documents/ESHATS/node_modules/serialport/parsers.js:25:17
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.parser (/home/manoj/Documents/ESHATS/node_modules/serialport/parsers.js:24:13)
at Object.SerialPort.opts.dataCallback (/home/manoj/Documents/ESHATS/node_modules/serialport/serialport.js:181:12)
at SerialPortFactory.SerialPort._emitData (/home/manoj/Documents/ESHATS/node_modules/serialport/serialport.js:396:20)
at afterRead (/home/manoj/Documents/ESHATS/node_modules/serialport/serialport.js:372:20)
```

Comment: serial data does not come in json, you must be manually formatting it to json string,  you have create a correct json object. It could be helpful if you share that code of yours.

Comment: Yeah, I did that...but problem is entire Jason string I created isn't passing in serial monitor...first two times..I get a distorted string

Comment: {""Xx","x":"59"} is the format I am getting after the data has distorted...is,I am unable to get the data in the way I specified..in program